# Native Facebook Login stopped working after SDK update to 3.14

Tags: ios, facebook

**Update**: Somehow the behaviour seems to have changed. I don't get the error message any more but the native login still does not work. Instead I am redirected to the web dialog if the Facebook app is not installed. Did Facebook remove the native login support for the last SDK?
The permissions I request were "public_profile", "email" and "user_likes". I also tried removing the "user_likes" permission, as it is not part of the basic permissions as stated here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#iosintegration
Still the native login dialog does not appear!

I recently updated my iOS Project to use the Facebook SDK version 3.14.0 (upgraded from 3.13.0 via CocoaPods). I read the upgrade notes and changed the permission "basic_info" to "public_profile" as recommended.

If I now call

```
FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:
                                   allowLoginUI:
                              completionHandler:
```

it only works via the web or Facebook App login. If I login natively in the OS settings, the login fails with

```
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)"
```

Has anyone experienced similar problems? Doesn't the native login work anymore this way? Or is it a problem with the "changed" permissions?

Regards
K

Comment: As I understand you need firstly make a call to read permission like openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler before use openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions

Comment: hmm, actually I AM still using openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler (updated my post above). But that seems to be deprecated (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/), allthough all examples still use that call. Maybe I should change that to openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI

Comment: Try without permission at all... Facebook will add email permission automatically. And see if it works

Comment: I already tried that. Not working.

Comment: Seems I misread the docu, openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:allowLoginUI:completionHandler is not deprecated, openActiveSessionWithPermissions is deprecated. So I am using the right call.

Comment: Check permissions in Facebook  settings for you application on Facebook site...  don't know what else to try

Comment: @Kim, u were tried the FB login in 3 ways, remote, native and safari, what the error u met

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I just ran to this issue also, here's the details on what has happened & how I fixed my app.

**Bottom line**
Due to the new login process wherein users can now approve / deny each requested permission (something not supported by the native ios integrated login), Facebook has changed the sdk's default login behavior to first try the Facebook fast app switch & then fall back on the web view, completely ignoring any ios system level Facebook credentials.

This is noted in the upgrade guide (form 3.13 > 3.14) here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading

Relevant portion:
"The default login behavior has changed from FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent to FBSessionLoginBehaviorWithFallbackToWebView."

**So what to do?**
 
Well, if you don't need any of the new things, FBLikeControl etc..., that were introduced in 3.14, you could just downgrade to 3.13.  However, if you want/need to use 3.14n there's an instance method on FBSession that takes the FBSessionLoginBehavior as a parameter: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/#openWithBehavior:completionHandler:

I updated the body of my method for opening a Facebook session from:

```
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_location"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
                                          ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
                                              [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
                                          }
    ];
```

to:

```
    FBSessionStateHandler completionHandler = ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:status error:error];
    };

    if ([FBSession activeSession].state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
        // we have a cached token, so open the session
        [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
                  completionHandler:completionHandler];
    } else {
        [self clearAllUserInfo];
        // create a new facebook session
        FBSession *fbSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"email", @"user_location"]];
        [FBSession setActiveSession:fbSession];
        [fbSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
                  completionHandler:completionHandler];
    }
```

**NOTE:** my clearAllUserInfo method includes the following lines:

```
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [FBSession renewSystemCredentials:^(ACAccountCredentialRenewResult result, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    }];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:nil];
```

It's also worth checking out the Facebook documentation on understanding sessions:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#sessions

Answer (score 3):

Check the permissions you ask for, in the new SDK (3.14) the basic_info permission has been deprecated and you need to submit the app for review for extended permissions. The basic permissions are:  public_profile, email, and user_friends

More info here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/upgrading

Comment: As I already stated: 'I read the upgrade notes and changed the permission "basic_info" to "public_profile" as recommended'. We also have gone through review for the basic permissions. Maybe it's the "user_likes" permission we also request, which hasn't been reviewed yet. But would that explain why it is working with the Facebook app and web login?

Comment: I got the login working yesterday just using the 3 basic permissions.

What do you exactly mean with this?:
`it only works via the web or Facebook App login. If I login natively in the OS settings, the login fails `

Also from the upgrade guide:
The New Facebook Login does not apply to iOS device account authentication.

The way it works in our app now is that i can indeed login via web or the Facebook app itself but the iOS settings have no "connection" anymore to my app. The app also doesn't show up anymore under settings->Facebook

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. So the documentation for https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#iosintegration and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.0#dialogs does not apply to the new SDK any more!? Because the iOS Native Login Dialog is still described there and it states that it's just a matter of separating requests for read and write permissions. The call used for the native login is exactly the same as for the other methods. But seems like Facebook wants to move away from native iOS auth anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may be missing this method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

It helped my case in which I had to migrate from 3.9.0 to the latest. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue as well. A quick workaround is simply to have the user delete their iOS Facebook credentials, login with your app, then put their credentials back in.

Answer (score 0):

if you use Facebook SDK 4.0, a login behavior can be set. The default value is `FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative`, but you may set it to `FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount`.

See below code:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
[loginManager logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
                    fromViewController:self
                               handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
  //TODO: process error or result
 }];
```