# How to do Facebook login in IOS using built-in facebook account?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, authentication

For a while now, my "Login with Facebook" button in my app doesn't show this dialog

[image: login dialog]

anymore, but redirecting me to Facebook app. Is this normal? Is it the FacebookSDK or my login flow has a mistake? I followed the latest instructions at [Facebook Login for IOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/v2.1#login-apicalls)

I want to create my own "Login with Facebook" button but rather than redirecting to Facebook app, I want the above dialog shown instead. Please help me, I don't know the term to search in Google. Anyone can tell me or point me to a good tutorial? Thanks

Comment: Are you logged into Facebook in the settings.app ?

Comment: Yes, I am.. In the settings app, I already setup my Facebook account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to Facebooks Graph API v2.x. You should read up on the changes here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: where? I don't see it. Sorry, but I don't think this answers my question about how can I let my app login to Facebook without redirecting to Facebook app..

Comment: @OscarYuandinata https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/04/30/the-new-facebook-login/

Comment: So why do some of the currently featured apps still use the above dialog when logging in to Facebook rather than redirect to Facebook app? Are they using outdated Facebook SDK or what?

Comment: yes I am guessing some of the a still using an earlier version. The earlier SDK can still be used for a specific period of time and will work until that runs out.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can downgrade to use Facebook SDK v3.13 or below.

OR

2) You can login with specified behavior `FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent`.

Sample code:

```
FBSessionStateHandler completionHandler = ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
        [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
    };
if ([FBSession activeSession].state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded) {
    // we have a cached token, so open the session
    [[FBSession activeSession] openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
              completionHandler:completionHandler];
} else {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    // create a new facebook session
    FBSession *fbSession = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"email", @"public_profile"]];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:fbSession];
    [fbSession openWithBehavior:FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent
              completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Reference: [Native Facebook Login stopped working after SDK update to 3.14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476499/native-facebook-login-stopped-working-after-sdk-update-to-3-14)