# How to make FBLoginView use system account by default

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Previous versions of iOS Facebook SDK (3.12) has allowed to specify loginBehavior property at FBLoginView to use system account: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.12/class/FBLoginView/

How can I implement same behavior (use FBSessionLoginBehaviorUseSystemAccountIfPresent) in latest version of SDK?

Comment: did u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23476499/native-facebook-login-stopped-working-after-sdk-update-to-3-14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the SDK are you having problems with. All the v3.x versions of the SDKs provide that loginBehavior property like you mentioned. In v4.0 of the SDK (released March 25), the FBLoginView is replaced by FBSDKLoginButton and still offers a loginBehavior property.

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why, but when I have checked documentation, there were no loginBehavior property presented.