# FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I'm using the Facebook SDK 4.3.0 in my objective c project.
There i need to login with facebook, using the account that is configured in settings.

For that i'm using:

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"] handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error || result.isCancelled){
        if (result.isCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"is canceled");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"is not canceled");
        }

        NSLog(@"facebook login error:%ld %@",(long)error.code,[error localizedDescription]);
        [self showErrorWithMessage:@"Couldn't login with Facebook"];
        return;
    }
    FBSDKAccessToken *token = [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken];
    NSLog(@"facebook access token data: %@",token.tokenString);
    [[ApiClient shared] requestAccessToAccountWithFacebookTokenString:token.tokenString];
}];
```

With a facebook account set in the ipad, i ran it but i the login fails, with the error description "The Facebook account has not been configured on the device" and the error code 307 (which, according to FBSDKLoginConstants.h it is FBSDKLoginSystemAccountUnavailableErrorCode).

I've tried in 2 ipads and in both happen the same.
If i use the FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative it works fine (meaning it uses the native app ignoring settings).

[How to make FBLoginView use system account by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29205414/how-to-make-fbloginview-use-system-account-by-default) ask the same, but the only answer says to use the loginBehaviour, which i already am using. (And i haven't reputation enough to ask in the comments).

Comment: i m also getting this isuue,have you find any solution for this??

Comment: Not yet. I'm currently using FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative, until i find a fix or facebook release a new sdk version

Comment: It's mid-October, and I'm still facing the same issue with the newest SDK. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Facebook SDK 4.7.0 the same issue.
SDK doesn't use NativeFlow for iOS version >= 9.0.0.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/Internal/ServerConfiguration/FBSDKServerConfigurationManager.m#L226-L228

All that you can do:
change code in SDK

OR
change the data that SDK stores at [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]

OR
use older version of FB SDK

Comment: you just mentioned some part of code in github, but what should we write there, can you write more information please?