# Objective-C : Force Use of Facebook App for Login?

Tags: objective-c, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have been browsing StackOverflow and Facebook docs for hours, and still can't seem to find a way to force Facebook Login SDK to use the installed Facebook App rather than popping up Safari.

Below is my code

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;

[login logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email"] fromViewController:self handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {

// custom logic

}];
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: do u have facebook app in device?

Comment: @priyadharshini yesi do

Answer (score 0):

FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount seems to be for logging in using the iOS builtin accounts system, not for using the Facebook app.

Try FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative for using the app.

Also see: [FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31276710/fbsdkloginbehaviorsystemaccount-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

try using `logInFromViewController` method of login manager.
it will take `FBSDKLoginConfiguration` param in which you can add Permissions also

`tracking = FBSDKLoginTrackingEnabled` will open app
`tracking = FBSDKLoginTrackingLimited` will continue  on browser.

```objectivec
FBSDKLoginManager *loginManager = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

FBSDKLoginConfiguration *config = [[FBSDKLoginConfiguration alloc] initWithPermissions:@[@"public_profile", @"email"] tracking:FBSDKLoginTrackingEnabled nonce:nonce];

[loginManager logInFromViewController:self configuration:config completion:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) 
    { //Your code here    }];
```